# How to prove that $T \mapsto \exp (T)$ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

> Let $\mathcal L (E)$ denote the space of all bounded linear operators on a normed linear space $E.$ Show that the map $\varphi : \mathcal L (E) \longrightarrow \mathcal L (E)$ defined by $T \longmapsto \exp (T),\ $ $T \in \mathcal L (E)$ is continuous.

I tried in the following way $:$

$$\begin{align*} \|\exp (T) - \exp (T_0) \|_{\text {op}}  & = \left \|\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {T^j} {j!} - \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {T_0^j} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}} \\ & = \left \| \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {T^j - T_0^j} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}} \\ & = \left \| \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {(T - T_0) (T^{j-1} + T^{j-2} T_0 + \cdots + T_0^{j-1} )} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}} \\ & \leq \|T - T_0\|_{\text {op}} \left \| \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {(T^{j-1} + T^{j-2} T_0 + \cdots + T_0^{j-1} )} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}}  \end{align*}$$

Now if we can make the quantity $\displaystyle \left \| \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {(T^{j-1} + T^{j-2} T_0 + \cdots + T_0^{j-1} )} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}}$ bounded then we are through. But how do I do that? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\left \| \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac {(T^{j-1} + T^{j-2} T_0 + \cdots + T_0^{j-1} )} {j!} \right \|_{\text {op}}\le \exp(\max(\|T\|,\|T_0\|))$ but more importantly your factorization of $T^j-T_0^j$ is incorrect when $T,T_0$ don't commmute.

Comment: @reuns: Indeed, for non-commuting $T$ and $T_0$, a correct version of the formula for the geometric sum is $T^j - T_0^j = \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} T^k(T-T_0)T_0^{j-1-k}$.

Comment: @reuns can you please check my answer?

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen's answer is fine, the polynomials are continuous (see Jochen Glueck's comment) thus so is exp because it is the (locally) uniformly convergent limit of a sequence of polynomials. Of course Jochen Glueck's comment also gives an explicit O(exp(2∥T0∥)∥T−T0∥) bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\|T\|$ and $\|T_0\|$ are both $<M$ then for the tail we have
$$\left\|\sum_{j=N}^\infty\frac {T^j}{j!}-\sum_{j=N}^\infty\frac {T_0^j}{j!}\right\|\le 2\sum_{j=N}^\infty\frac {M^j}{j!}$$
and can be made $<\frac \epsilon2$, say, if only you make $N$ big enough. What is left, is polynomial.

Comment: Sir here $T \in \mathcal L (E)$ is varying. Then how do I get hold of $\|T\|_{\text {op}}\ $?